# CachedDbAuthManager Clearing Cache for particular role of user

Tags: caching, yii, yii-extensions

Using the Auth Manager of Yii I used CachedDbAuthManager. Once SQL executes for specific role against a user it caches the result. Next time records fetched from cache. Now once admin delete the role for a particular user it still remains in cache.

What is solution to this Problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Yii's [Cache Dependency Implementation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.data#cache-dependency).

You could eg. invalidate a cache when the admin edits an auth table, see also the [database cache dependency](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCacheDependency). Often this is done just by looking for the latest eg. `modified_at` time, but this column is not part of the standard auth tables.

From the database cache man page:

> CDbCacheDependency represents a dependency based on the query result of a SQL statement.

Comment: Yes this is what the extension is doing at the back!

Answer (score 0):

There is another extension [SingleDbAuthManager](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/singledbauthmanager/) which is doing nearly the same thing. It reads whole auth tree at once and cache it.

The performance of both **SingleDbAuthManager** and **CachedDbAuthManager** is vering. CachedDbAuthManager taking less time but fails to update cache in my case.